# Open weather ajax

Tags: ajax, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to do a ajax call to Openweathermap API and my variables are not being updated once the function leaves ajax. Can someone please explain to me why my var tmp is not being updated.

```
    var url1 = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=" + marker.position.lat()+"&lon="+marker.position.lng() + "&type=accurate&units=imperial&mode=json&APPID=8cbc2d4c3edf26435cf160f3cee969ed";
    var tmp;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url1,
    async: false,
    success:function (data) {
tmp =data.list[0].main.temp +"F " + data.list[0].weather[0].description;
console.log(tmp); //it logs correctly here 
  }
});
console.log(tmp); //it says it's undefined here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is async, not synchronous

- your first TMP within the ajax callback will wait for the ajax to complete before execution.
- your second TMP outside of your ajax callback will execute straight away before waiting the ajax to complete

You can read up on 
https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/

some of the js solutions

- callbacks ( beginner1 )
- Async.js  ( beginner2 )
- Promises  ( intermediate )
- ES6 async/await ( advance )

Comment: async is set to false in my ajax call how come it acting otherwise?

Comment: its deprecated on jquery api doc, and why would you want sync? it will FREEZE the browser till result is retrieved